# selectCheckboxMenu filter values not reset on refresh

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In my dataTable, I want to use `selectCheckboxMenu` as a filter on one of columns (like in [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml) example on **Color** column). My column looks like this:

```
<p:column filterBy="#{record.typeString}" filterMatchMode="in">
     <f:facet name="filter">
         <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Types" onchange="PF('dataTable').filter();"
                               panelStyle="width:125px" scrollHeight="150">
             <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.typeStrings}" />
         </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
     </f:facet>
     <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Type"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{record.typeString}" />
</p:column>
```

In `myBean`, there's a method which returns values I want to have on the panel in filter:

```
public List<String> getTypeStrings() {
    List<String> typeStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    typeStrings.add("typeString1");
    typeStrings.add("typeString2");
    typeStrings.add("typeString3");
    typeStrings.add("typeString4");
    return typeStrings;
}
```

Filtering works as desired. After deploying to server, all checkboxes on the panel in filter are unchecked. When I check some of them, filter is applied. The problem is that after page refresh, filtering is not applied anymore (desired), but checkboxes keep their check states (some of them are checked). In the [PF showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml), all checkboxes are unchecked after refresh as expected.

I tried to add `value="selectedTypeStrings"` to `selectCheckboxMenu`, added this variable (list) to the bean and clear it in `@PostContruct` method, but it didn't help.

How can I reset all those checkboxes after page refresh?

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Not really, unfortunately. From what I remember I just used some workaround. Sorry I don't have that code anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much anyway for sharing